# Create collision between array of animation and UIImages app development

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have code for an animating bear but i need to check collision between its animation and a regular UIImageView. Any suggestions? I looked at other answers but my code isn't the same. Here's what I have so far. Or should i use SpriteKit. I'd rather not though.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSArray *imageNames = @[@"bear1.gif", @"bear2.gif", @"bear3.gif", @"bear4.gif",
                        @"bear5.gif", @"bear6.gif"];

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

// Normal Animation
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(768, 800, 169, 217)];
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;


[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];


[UIView animateWithDuration:7 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
    animationImageView.frame = CGRectMake(-10, 800, 169, 217);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    animationImageView.hidden = YES;
}];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your animations block you can check to see when the frame of your animating view crosses or is about to cross the frame of your UIImageView. When this condition is met, you stop the animation